# How can I collect all JFrames in one project with all images?

Tags: java

I want to ask how can I collect all frames from my friends with all the images? I tried this way in all frames but still not work!

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
at oopo_project.Login.initComponents(Login.java:94)
at oopo_project.Login.<init>(Login.java:28)
at oopo_project.Oopo_project.main(Oopo_project.java:16)
/Users/raghad/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

And here is the code where I put the image icon class.
Login frame:

```
public Login() {
    initComponents();
    connect();
    ImageIcon L1 = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("BACK.PNG"));
    ImageIcon L2 = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("PROJECTPIC.PNG"));
    ImageIcon L3 = new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("USERNAMEPIC.PNG"));
}
```

Comment: From _javadoc_ for method [getResource(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) _[returns] null if no resource with this name is found_

Comment: how can I fix the resource? I out all these pictures inside the package

Comment: Are you using a build tool, like [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) or [Ant](https://ant.apache.org/) ?

Comment: no not using any tool

Comment: File `BACK.PNG` (and all other image files) need to be in same folder as file `Login.class`, i.e. the compiled java class.